# Trace of roots of unity has valuation more than 1 in uramified field

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, p-adic-groups, traces, roots-of-unity

Let $F$ be a finite extension of $\mathbb{Q}_p$ (p is prime) and $K/F$ be a unramified extension of prime degree $\ell (\neq p)$. Denote $\mu_K$ be the group of roots of unity in $K.$ Does there exist an element $\zeta\in\mu_K$ such that $tr_{K/F}\zeta\in P^t_F$ for $t\ge 1$?

If the answer is yes, what is the largest $t$ with the above property?

Comment: Existence looks easy: lift any trace-zero element of the finite field of
$p^l$ elements (other than zero).  Largest $t$ looks rather trickier.
What (if any) is the intended application?

Comment: Thank you @NoamD.Elkies. This is part of a problem related trace on p - adic fields. Can you suggest some reference to work out this ?

Comment: Sorry, I can't, and I'm rarely the one to ask for references . . .